# Spline Interpolation Performance in Scala vs Java

Tags: java, performance, scala, interpolation, spline

I translated [this spline interpolation algorithm](http://commons.apache.org/math/api-2.2/src-html/org/apache/commons/math/analysis/interpolation/SplineInterpolator.html#line.53) from apache.commons.math from Java into Scala in the most straightforward way I could think of (see below).  The function I ended up with runs 2 to 3 times slower than the original Java code.  My guess is that the problem stems from the extra loops coming from the calls to `Array.fill`, but I can't think of a straightforward way to get rid of them.  Any suggestions on how to make this code perform better?  (It would also be nice to write it in a more concise and/or functional way -- suggestions on that front would be appreciated as well.)

```
type Real = Double

def mySplineInterpolate(x: Array[Real], y: Array[Real]) = {

  if (x.length != y.length)
    throw new DimensionMismatchException(x.length, y.length)

  if (x.length < 3)
    throw new NumberIsTooSmallException(x.length, 3, true)

  // Number of intervals.  The number of data points is n + 1.                                                                         
  val n = x.length - 1

  // Differences between knot points                                                                                                   
  val h = Array.tabulate(n)(i => x(i+1) - x(i))

  var mu: Array[Real] = Array.fill(n)(0)
  var z: Array[Real] = Array.fill(n+1)(0)
  var i = 1
  while (i < n) {
    val g = 2.0 * (x(i+1) - x(i-1)) - h(i-1) * mu(i-1)
    mu(i) = h(i) / g
    z(i) = (3.0 * (y(i+1) * h(i-1) - y(i) * (x(i+1) - x(i-1))+ y(i-1) * h(i)) /
            (h(i-1) * h(i)) - h(i-1) * z(i-1)) / g
    i += 1
  }

  // cubic spline coefficients --  b is linear, c quadratic, d is cubic (original y's are constants)                                   
  var b: Array[Real] = Array.fill(n)(0)
  var c: Array[Real] = Array.fill(n+1)(0)
  var d: Array[Real] = Array.fill(n)(0)

  var j = n-1
  while (j >= 0) {
    c(j) = z(j) - mu(j) * c(j + 1)
    b(j) = (y(j+1) - y(j)) / h(j) - h(j) * (c(j+1) + 2.0 * c(j)) / 3.0
    d(j) = (c(j+1) - c(j)) / (3.0 * h(j))
    j -= 1
  }

  Array.tabulate(n)(i => Polynomial(Array(y(i), b(i), c(i), d(i))))
}
```

Comment: scala is built on top of java, so its not surprising that it will not be faster.

Comment: No, Scala is built on top of the JVM, and the compiler can emit JVM bytecode directly.  Also, Scala is often the same speed as Java and, in some cases (e.g. when using specialization), is faster.  However, to get code of equivalent speed, one sometimes has to write non-idiomatic Scala.  I suggest the OP profile his code to see where the time is being spent in the Scala & Java code.

Answer (score 6):

You can get rid of all the `Array.fill` since a new array is always initialized with 0 or null, depending on whether it is a value or a reference (booleans are initialized with false, and characters with `\0`).

You might be able to simplify the loops by zipping arrays, but you'll only make it slower. The only way functional programming (on the JVM anyway) is going to help you make this faster is if you make it non-strict, such as with a `Stream` or a view, and then you go ahead and *not* use all of it.

Comment: Ok, replacing the `Array.fill`s with `Array.ofDim`s almost recovers the performance of the Java version.  Thanks.

Comment: @davidsd I didn't see any multidimensional arrays there. A simple `new Array[Real](n)` ought to suffice, though only now I see you are working with `Real`, not `Double`.

Comment: Ack -- I should have included this in the code above, but I'm using `type Real = Double` at the moment.  What's the difference between `Array.ofDim[Real](n)` and `new Array[Real](n)`?

Comment: @davidsd The `ofDim` method is just intended for multidimensional arrays -- I'm surprised a single dimensional version of it even exists. It is implemented in terms of `new Array`, though, so you are just adding an extra layer of indirection by using it.